# 一つしか違いません in this context,

Tags: grammar

A is the sempai of B, both are girls

> A『私にも妹が居たら‥‥アナタみたいな感じなのかしらね？』
>
> B『ちょっと違うと思いますよ。』
>
> B『**私とAさんは一つしか違いませんし**‥‥それに、私の妹は私とは正反対の元気な子ですから。』
>
> A『性格とか年の数はどうでもいいのよ、いわゆる気分の問題なんだから。』
>
> B『んー、良くわからないですね‥‥。』

me and Aさん only have 1 thing (age/grade?) different?

- i don't think this is true, since there are big differences in terms of 性格 between A and B as well.

otherwise, how should i interpret 私とAさんは一つしか違いませんし?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ひとつ refers to an age (difference). Also note that [いくつ](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B9%BE%E3%81%A4) can mean "how old" in Japanese.

> いくつになったの？ How old are you now?
>   みっつ！ Three!

Comment: oh you mean "me and Aさん are only a year part" ? i see